# How can I calculate how often one string appears in a column compared to another string?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column in my Google Spreadsheet which contains either `OK` or `NOK` (acceptance testing).

How can I calculate the percentage for how often `OK` appears compared to `NOK`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
= COUNTIF( A1:A; "OK" ) / COUNTA( A1:A )
```

`A1:A` defining the column in which the OK/NOK values are defined. If you have more values than OK and NOK, use this:

```
= COUNTIF( A1:A; "OK" ) / ( COUNTIF( A1:A; "OK" ) + COUNTIF( A1:A; "NOK" ) )
```

Comment: The second formula is perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use this excel formula:

Assuming `Column A` has list of entries

```
=(COUNTIF(A:A,"=OK")/COUNTA(A:A))*100
```